# MATLAB Listening on TCP/IP port

Tags: iphone, matlab, tcp, ip

I have seen already a few articles about this topic, but most of these were from 3-4 years ago and I have to believe someone has done this before. Does anyone know if there is a way to have a MATLAB program that will listen on a specified port number. I am trying to transmit information to MATLAB over a local network, or potentially internet, and have MATLAB do stuff with it? Any suggestions?

My other option is just to send everything to an SQL server, and then have MATLAB poll this server. I however was concerned about the speed of this because MATLAB needs to be spitting out stuff in "real-time" or as close to as possible.

*Note information will be taken from an iPhone and transmitted over Wi-Fi*

Answer (score 1):

I would use a language which is interfaced through Matlab, such as C over mex-files or Java.

Answer (score 0):

This is my example. Android user sends a file name and the file to matlab TCP server. Then, matlab TCP server receives a line which is file name and file data.

```
   t = tcpip('0.0.0.0', 8000, 'NetworkRole', 'Server');
    set(t, 'InputBufferSize', 900000);

    fprintf('waiting for client');
    fopen(t);
    pause(1);

    fprintf('client connected');

    fid = fopen('temp','w+');
    file_name = fgetl(t);

    % read first line

    while (get(t, 'BytesAvailable') > 0 )
        pause(2);
        t.BytesAvailable
        data = fread(t, t.BytesAvailable);
        pause(2);
        fwrite(fid, data);
    end

    copyfile('temp',['../../data/' file_name]);

    fclose(t);
    fclose(fid);
```